# context menu disappears on menu item click

Tags: android, contextmenu

I am using a `context menu` for my textview.I made setCheckable() property as true for every menu items. When i click on first menu item it is checked but menu is disappearing. Is it possible to check more than one item in a context menu?

Answer (score 0):

Did you try this..

```
@Override
public void onCreateContextMenu(ContextMenu menu, View v, ContextMenuInfo menuInfo) {
    super.onCreateContextMenu(menu, v, menuInfo);
    menu.setHeaderTitle(R.string.menu_title);
    MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.context_menu, menu);

    // loop for menu items
    for (int i = 0; i < menu.size(); ++i) {
        MenuItem mi = menu.getItem(i);
        // check the Id as you wish
        if (mi.getItemId() == R.id.item2) {
            mi.setChecked(true); 
        }
    }
}


        MenuItem mi = menu.findItem(R.id.item2)
```

Answer (score 0):

Context menu's are built to be dismissed on tap as per the standard UX pattern. You can try using a Dialog with CheckBoxes and ok / cancel button instead.